# Haskell: how to treat big combinatorial Lists?

Tags: list, haskell, infinite

just recently I tried to write a program which basically simulates a simple system from an Online Game. The idea behind that is, to let the program calculate the most efficient set of items for the most possible stat efficiency from a set. To clarify this a bit more:
you've got 8 item Slots and 74 different items, you can't use any item twice, and it doesn't matter which item is in which slot. I'am not even yet trying to calculate one set of stats, I'am stuck way earlier!

So the problem with this is the number of possibilities which are (74^8) before filtering and (74 choose 8) after filtering.
My program already starts lagging when I just try head(permu' 2).
Since I know Haskell is supposed to work with infinite Lists, how does it work with a List of 899 trillion entries? Well I know obviously it takes a lot of capacity for the PC but that's why I am here to ask:

**How do I treat a big List in Haskell so that I can work with it?**

the function simplified looks like this:

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort [a] = [a]
quicksort (x:xs) = (quicksort [y | y <- xs, y <= x]) ++ [x] ++ (quicksort [z | z <- xs , z > x])

eliminatedouble [] = []
eliminatedouble (x:xs) = if x `elem` xs then eliminatedouble xs else x:(eliminatedouble xs)

permu' n | n>8 = error "8 is max"
         | otherwise = eliminatedouble (filter allSatisfied (generate n))
   where
      generate 0 = [[]]
      generate x = [quicksort (a:xs) | a <- [1..74], xs <- generate (x-1)]
      allSatisfied [] = True
      allSatisfied (x:xs) = (checkConstraint x xs) && (allSatisfied xs)
      checkConstraint x xs = not (doubled x xs)
      doubled x xs = x `elem` xs
```

would be interesting to know how to do all this way cheaper.

Thanks in advance, regards.

Comment: For future reference: `quicksort` -> `Data.List.sort`; `eliminatedouble` -> `Data.List.nub`. The `doubled` alias for `elem` seems odd. Also, `nub` is generally quite slow compared to a `Data.Set`-based implementation, and `allSatisfied` will likely also be sped up a lot by using `Data.Set`. But as described in my answer, the biggest win will come from only generating the elements you care about in the first place rather than generating tons of stuff you don't care about and filtering.

Answer (score 3):

You're making this much more difficult than it needs to be.

```
choose 0 xs = [[]]
choose n [] = []
choose n (x:xs) = map (x:) (choose (n-1) xs) ++ choose n xs
```

In my interpreter, `choose 5 [1..74]` takes about 22 seconds to compute all the entries and `choose 6 [1..74]` takes 273 seconds. Additionally, `choose 8 [1..74]` starts chugging through combinations straight away; I estimate that it would take about 6 hours to generate them all. N.B. that this is in the interpreter, with no optimization or other fanciness going on; possibly it could go much faster if you give GHC a chance to figure out how.

Assuming that you intend to do some nontrivial computation on each element of `choose 8 [1..74]`, I suggest you either schedule a largish chunk of time or else think about solutions that do not do an exhaustive search -- perhaps using some heuristics to get an approximate answer, or figuring out how to do some pruning to cut out large, uninteresting swaths of the search space.

Comment: Exhaustively checking `nCr 74 8` choices? Might just be doable on a top-notch cluster, definitely not feasible on a PC.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Actually, after doing some back-of-the-envelope calculation, I'm more inclined to believe it would be possible... if you don't mind computing for a few days. Depends on the user's goals, I think! I've updated my answer to be more hopeful.

Comment: You're right, I also had an approximation in my head and it was actually a couple orders of magnitude too pessimistic. Anyway this is definitely a task that would be worth to parallelise.

Comment: Why is this so much faster than listcomprehension? I'am kinda new to Haskell so I don't really know... And anyways, you guys think I should drop this project, since it is kinda important to have the 8... And it's not really that easy to cut out results because every result can potentially be important, the complete list from 74 choose 8 is gonna be sorted based on the entries in the objects which are basically tuples with 45 entries each... Your function is way faster than the one I used obviously. Would it be more successful to work on this on an object based program language like java?

Comment: @nub The speed difference is not in list comprehension vs. not, but in choosing a better algorithm. Compare: my version need not eliminate duplicates, do any sorting, or verify that any particular predicate holds of elements or of the entire list. That's a lot of work that simply need not be done in my version compared to yours. I doubt it will be better to abandon Haskell -- 74 choose 8 is just a big number, and you can't fix that by choosing a different language.